# how to add list inside the li element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I made a static example after studying from this site:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/web/treeview/overview

Now I want to add more items as a submenu. How can I add a submenu of which is already a submenu of parent.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CDAVZ/580/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('#one').click(function(){
       alert('one') 

    });
       $('#two').click(function(){
       alert('two') 

    });
    $('#three').click(function(){
       alert('three') 

    });
    // If you want to disable showing the context menu when right clicking
    // on the document, the code below would do the trick.
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e)
    {
        return false;
    }); 

    var $tree = $("#tree").kendoTreeView(
    {
        dragAndDrop: true,
        select: function (event)
        {
            var $item = $(event.node);
            console.log( $item );
            alert( "selected" );
        }
    });


    // Find the item you want to select...
    var $selected = $('#selected');
    var $treePath = $selected.parentsUntil($tree, "li");

    var treeView = $tree.data('kendoTreeView');

    // Expand the tree in order to show the selected item
    treeView.expand( $treePath );

    // Gotta make both calls...
    treeView.select( $selected );
    treeView.trigger( 'select', {node: $selected} );
});
```

Comment: It looks like the append function doesn't fully do what the OP was looking to do. http://jsfiddle.net/CDAVZ/581/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the treeView object to append the value, you should be all set. the first argument is the object to add, the second argument is the node to add it to. It takes jquery selector items, so the following will work.

```
$('#one').click(function(){
    treeView.append({text: 'new item'}, $("li:contains('Item1') ul"));
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CDAVZ/582/